# R flexdashboard remove title bar

Tags: r, r-markdown, dashboard, titlebar, flexdashboard

[image: Blue bar at the top, meant for a title]

I am working on a project using `rMarkdown` and the `flexdashboard` package from `rStudio`. Everything is coming together nicely. But I would like to remove the blue title bar you see at the top of the image here.

We are dropping this html page into a window so it becomes a second title bar, which looks terrible. Is there a function in `flexdashboard` to remove this entire apparatus?

Here is the YAML and the first chunk you see just below the blue bar in the photograph. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

````
---
title: New Hampshire Statewide Age Adjusted Incedence Rates of Lyme
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=TRUE}

```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### 
```{r, aarState, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

library(flexdashboard)
library(rbokeh)
#load state-wide age adjusted rates

aar<-read.csv("stateAAR.csv")
figure(title=" Age Adjusted Rates by Year",width= 1500, height =600) %>%
  ly_segments(year, lci*100000, year, uci*100000, data=aar, color = "#b37700", width = 1) %>%
  ly_points(year, adj.rate*100000, glyph = 21, size=6, data = aar, hover= "<strong>Rate per 100,000:</strong> @rateHundThou </br> <strong>Upper Confidence:</strong> @uciHT </br><strong> Lower Confidence:</strong> @lciHT " , color="#666622" )%>%

  x_axis(label ='Year')%>%
  y_axis(label ='Age Adjusted Rate')


```  

Row
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just add CSS styling directly to your markdown document (no JQuery required):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---
<style>

body {
  padding-top:0px
}

.navbar{
  visibility: hidden
}

</style>


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
hist(iris$Sepal.Length)

```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
hist(iris$Sepal.Width)
```

### Chart C

```{r}
hist(iris$Petal.Length)
```
````

Results in:[image]

Comment: Of course, use CSS directly...I always think of jQuery in the first place :P +1

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any flexdashboard option. But you could use jQuery to remove the navbar and move the body up. Just include the following snippet right after your YAML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbar').remove();
  $('body').css('padding-top', '0px');
});
</script>
```

I think this leaves the main navigation bar of the parent document untouched. If not it might need some lsight modification.

Comment: Awesome answer. This worked great. gave points to the style only because it is much easier for non-JS people to add to rMarkdown. Thank you for a great answer!