# flexdashboard - change title bar color

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I want to change the title bar color of a flexdashboard.

I've found an example for removing it - SE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637756/r-flexdashboard-remove-title-bar), but given that I don't know any CSS/JQuery, I had to ask.

I want to change the bar color to red, and the text to black.

Anyone?

Edit (example below):

```
---
title: "DB: Contact information"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

<style>                     
.navbar {
  background-color:crimson;
  border-color:black;
}
.navbar-brand {
color:black!important;
}


</style>   


Dashboard
=====================================  

Test. Test. Test. 

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Clustered Data
```

Result: 
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could customize the style sheets in a `<style>...</style>` block like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---
<style>                     
.navbar {
  background-color:red;
  border-color:black;
}
.navbar-brand {
color:black!important;
}
</style>                    

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
plot(0)
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
plot(0)
```

### Chart C

```{r}
plot(0)
```
````

Or use

```
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    css: styles.css
```

to put your custom styles in a separate `styles.css` file.

[image]

Comment: Yes it works. But it doesn't change the collor of the buttons background/text.

Comment: Any idea how I can make them blend in with the navbar? (i know i should learn bootstrap)

Comment: @Prometheus Hm I dunno, please edit your original post and add a minimal example for copy-paste-run in the veins I did.

Comment: hi again. thanks for the help. I just updated the OP.

Comment: @Prometheus Thanks, can you include buttons in your post so I can test it?

Comment: I updated the post. I am including the buttons through markdown.

Comment: @Prometheus Thanks again. I tried `.navbar, [data-toggle=tab], .navbar-brand  {
  background-color:crimson!important;
  border-color:black;
  color:black!important;
}` and it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you @lukeA!