# Rmarkdown Interactive documents Bootswatch theme colour incorrect

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard, bootswatch

In R markdown using Flexdashboard template, colours of Bootswatch themes don's seem matching what's shown on the Bootswatch website

For example, using `flatly` theme

```
---
title: "Test Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: flatly
runtime: shiny
---
```

What I got is like this:
flatly theme in rmarkdown flexdashboard theme

[image]

What the flatly theme looks like from Bootswatch is like this:
flatly theme from Bootswatch

[image]

Is there some settings that I need to specify to get the correct colour? Or for Rmarkdown Bootswatch themes are set to look differently?

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/126. You might want to customise that too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305381/flexdashboard-change-tittle-bar-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following JS chunk solves the problem:

````
```{js}
$('.navbar-inverse').removeClass('navbar-inverse').addClass('navbar-
default');
```
````