# YAML title font and color in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, title, flexdashboard

Is there a way to change the font and color in the YAML title in a R markdown flexdashboard?
Here is the code for the YAML header I am trying to change:

```
---
title: "Greenhouse gases and weather data"
fontsize: 30
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
    theme: readable

---
```

Comment: You either have to use a theme or create a CSS file.
You can see the themes that are standard here: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html
That site also details how to call the themes in the YAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option would be to add a CSS code chunk anywhere in the dashboard

````
```{css}

body > div.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top > div > div.navbar-header > span.navbar-brand {
  
    font-size: 26px;
    color: red;
}

```
````

Answer (score 0):

as Kat said,  the color is set by CSS , therefore you can change the behaviour in the .rmd file itself, or in the underlying theme template .css file.

somewhere located at:

/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/flexdashboard/rmarkdown/templates/flex_dashboard/resources

add (to the rmd) or look for and change (the .css) to :

```
<style>                     
.navbar {
  background-color:white;
  border-color:blue;
}
.navbar-brand {
color:blue!important;
}
</style>
```

This will revert the default color scheme of the top navbar

at the moment i dont know a simple YAML - argument solution for this
( but looking into css will gain you much more
versatility along the way, than relying on the YAML options)

Comment: Thanks Kat, user12256545 and Nata for all the hints. Nata’s solution worked out while placed in the rmd body (not in the YAML). cheers

Comment: actually yours worked too; here is another solution on stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305381/flexdashboard-change-title-bar-color?noredirect=1&lq=1